# Help remembering a short story about a man on mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

So I'm having trouble remembering a short story I read about 3 or 4 years ago. I'm a little hazy with some of the details but I think that it was about this one man who had a high ranking among a military organization on earth that was sent to a weather monitoring station on Mars to check on the status of the man previously there who people thought was going insane. The man claims there are Martian monsters in these certain electrical storms and when the monsters appear they make a static like noise. The story ends with the two men trapped in a room after the monsters get into their facility. I might be a little wrong with some of the details but the whole idea of it should be right. I know it's a little long but any help is appreciated.